# "Segmentation Fault" on modifying aodv.cc energy

Tags: ns2

I am trying to modify aodv.cc so that it calculates energy of each node in the grid. 
I am adding these two lines of code: `iNode = (MobileNode *)(Node::get_node_by_address(index));  iEnergy=iNode->energy_model()-> energy();`

Which I get a segmentation fault for the second line when I try to run the tcl code .
This is the configuration in the tcl script:

```
$ns node-config -adhocRouting AODV \
-llType LL \
-macType Mac/802_11 \
-ifqType Queue/DropTail/PriQueue \
-ifqLen 50 \
-addressingType flat\
-antType Antenna/OmniAntenna \
-propType Propagation/TwoRayGround \
-phyType Phy/WirelessPhy \
-channel [new Channel/WirelessChannel] \
-energyModel "EnergyModel" \
               -initialEnergy 3.4 \
               -txPower 0.33 \
               -rxPower 0.1 \
               -idlePower 0.05 \
               -sleepPower 0.03 \
-topoInstance $topo \
-agentTrace ON \
-routerTrace ON \
-macTrace OFF \
-movementTrace ON
```

I will appreciate if anyone can solve this issue

Comment: Have you checked the values of `iNode` and `iNode->energy_model()` to ensure they're not null?

Comment: @Barmar yes. iNode is nut null but i guess iNode->energy_model() has a problem. and i don't know how should i print in this situation.

Comment: Assign it to a temporary variable: `em_ptr = iNode->energy_model();` then check the value of `em_ptr`.

Comment: 22 simulation examples, EnergyModel : EnergyModel-examples-4.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U8YFgZPRHVm2rrg9iD4WV0nrMP4tsYAG/view?usp=sharing ... All ~2500 examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing